# WooCommerce Print Order Confirmation PDF

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Our business uses the Name Your Price tool in WooCommerce to allow our customers to pay their invoices. However, there is no way for them to print an order confirmation or some kind of receipt on the front-end of our site. I have a plugin that sends this link to our customer's email and allows us to print in the admin dashboard, but I'd also like to include it as a button or link on the front-end too. Is this possible?